# equivalence classes vs partitions in imperfect-information games

Tags: game-theory, equivalence-relations

I am reading Multiagent Systems by Yoav Shoham, and in chapter 5 about extensive games, the [definition of imperfect-information games](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k74EJ.png) extends the perfect-information games definition with equivalence classes.

But it is also mentioned that,

> "Perfect-information games can be thought of as a special case of
> imperfect- information games, in which every equivalence class of each
> partition is a singleton. "

I understand what equivalence classes being singleton for players would make it a perfect-information game, but what is a *partition* that's mentioned here?

In this [Example Game Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyWBw.png), I know that player 1 has two equivalence classes - first at the root node (so only one decision node) with available actions L and R, and the second with two decision nodes with actions l and r. Player 2 has one equivalence class of one decision node with actions A and B.

What are the *partitions* in this example? I am having a difficult time relating the two ideas.

Edit: I have attached the definition they have given for imperfect-information games

Comment: Well, I expect they define it...but I'd say that you partition the possible game states according to your ability to distinguish them.  Thus, if you can't tell state $A$ from state $B$, those two states are in the same equivalence class with respect to the information partition.  Of course, with perfect knowledge you can always identify the state uniquely.

Comment: Unsure if you are asking about partitions in general or the specific ones of your situation, but the word partition is a set theoretic term that refers to the division of all elements of a set into all its equivalence classes, given some relation.

Comment: @lulu I have attached a definition that they have given in the book, but that doesn't explicitly explain what partitions mean here. What is information partition?

Comment: Well, if I were defining it I'd say that two game states are equivalent iff players can not distinguish them.  The information partition, then, is just the collection of equivalence classes.  Imagine that at some point a player rolls an ordinary die, but the value isn't exposed at the time.  Then you have $6$ equivalent states (indexed by the possible die values).  Again, I don't know this source so they might have a different approach.